# Are immutability of variable and immutability of value independent concepts in Rust?

Tags: rust

Why the first example invalid and the next one valid?

```
let a = String::from("text");
a.push_string("more text");
```

versus

```
let a = &mut s3;
a.push_string("more text");
```

Doesn't the left part of the assignment (`let a` in both cases) refer to where `a` can point to, rather than what is the content of the memory block is that it's referring to?

Isn't this inconsistent behavior confusing? This would be more consistent:

```
let a = String::from("text");

// should be valid because the reference stays to the same "thing", it's the "thing" itself that changes
a.push_string("more text");

// should be invalid because "a" must always reference the "same thing"
a = String::from("entirely new text");
```

If we are making the distinction between immutability of the variable vs immutability of value, shouldn't the immutability of variable be determined by `mut` in the variable declaration?

Comment: What's `s3`? You didn't show us its definition.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking "why was the language designed this way, wouldn't it be more consistent if ...", which is off topic here as opinion-based. If you are asking something different, please clarify your question.

Comment: I think there's probably some logic behind it and I'm just trying to understand it. That's why it sounds like a suggestion but in fact I'm just trying to make sense of it.

Comment: "Doesn't the left part of the assignment (let a in both cases) refer to where a can point to, rather than what is the content of the memory block is that it's referring to?" that doesn't really mean anything? `mut` is associated with a binding, from a mutable binding you can get a mutable reference (and thus modify the object), from an immutable one you can't, barring inner mutability. Various people have expressed doubt about the usefulness of `mut` at all, but not about its consistency, `mut` is consistent.

Comment: The difference is that in the case where you assign `String::new()` to `a`, in that case `a` doesn't _point to_ the string, it _owns_ the string. It's not a reference. You may be thinking of languages like C#, Java, JavaScript, etc. where you only ever have references to values (other than primitives). Rust is more like C++ in that values can be directly owned, but references also exist as a separate concept.

Comment: It's like you are allowed to move out of variable not marked `mut` to a variable marked `mut` and mutate it there. You move the mutable reference and mutate it (well, you don't really move it, you reborrow it, but the essence is the same).

Comment: Your suggestion makes no sense, because if you can get a mutable reference to a location (something `push_str` requires) you can *replace* the underlying object: just take a mutable reference, and assign to its dereference. `a = String::from(...)` is not functionally different from `let b = &mut a; *b = String::from(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the type signature for [String::push_str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str).

```rust
pub fn push_str(&mut self, string: &str);
```

`String::push_str` takes a mutable reference, a `&mut String`.

In the first example, the type of `a` is `String`. With a normal `let` binding, not `let mut`, the compiler will refuse to let us reference it mutably, e.g. `&mut a`.

In the second example, `a` already has the type `&mut String`. It is already a mutable reference to it doesn't need to be converted. It is already the correct type for being passed to `String::push_string`.

To reiterate, taking a `&mut a` is not allowed unless `a` is a mutable binding (`let mut a = ...;`). The first example tries to take a `&mut a`. The second example does not need to take a `&mut a` because `a` is already a `&mut String`.

Comment: Thanks. What I missed, is that while those declarations look the same, that is only because of the type inference. The types of the variables are different, and that is even suggested by the IDE, they are `String` and `&mut String` respectively.

Comment: They are apples and oranges, as @cdhowie suggested, first is ownership, another is mutable reference. I'm thinking of all assignments as references because of my C# background.